# Log4j: socketappender - How to capture logs in localfile when remotehost is down

Tags: java, elasticsearch, log4j, logstash, apache-commons-logging

I have a scenario where we are logging to remote logstash host. Now as per log4j documentation, For SocketAppender, if remote host is down, log events will be simply dropped.  I would like to customize socket appender in order to capture those dropped logs in a local log file. So that nothing is missed.

I tried but was unable to.
There were 2 methods in socketappender connect and append(event)

But it seems to me, append is called only if connection is successful. Althought connect method wasn't returning anything

So how do i capture that event in localfile in case remotehost is down

Ref: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/xref/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html

I also tried Fallbackerror handler. But it only logs once and then no more logging. So basically it doesnt seems to work

Comment: How about two Appenders ?

Comment: but that will create 2 copies of same records...i only want to capture thos logs locally which were dropped, so that I can easily manually process them later

Comment: Another issue with SocketAppender is that the timestamp of the event is not  conveyed properly, i.e. the timestamp of the event in Logstash will be the time when the log event gets to Logstash, not the real time when the log was generated by the application. You should prefer logging locally and tailing the local file with logstash and you solve both problems.

Comment: timestamp is not a problem, i am generating timestamp in my code and sending that value as one of the field in logs, so eventtime is not an issue at all. lets go back to socketappender :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. Use **Two Appenders** at a time. One Socket Appender and second **File Appender**. So, at a time, you logs will go both in Socket Appender to Remote Host , as well as in the file on your local.

Here is an example of this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
 <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
 <appender name="FA" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="c:/logs/log4j/log2.out"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="conversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="server" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender">
    <param name="Port" value="4712"/>
    <param name="ReconnectionDelay" value="10000"/>
    <param name="RemoteHost" value="localhost"/>
</appender>
<root>
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="server"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FA"/>
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

You can use FA for Appending into file and Server for Remote.

**UPDATE**

You can try Log4j 2.7 Failover Apppender. Once, the socket Appender fails, the application will use secondary file appender.

Example-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log" filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz"
                 ignoreExceptions="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT" ignoreExceptions="false">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <Failover name="Failover" primary="RollingFile">
      <Failovers>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      </Failovers>
    </Failover>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Failover"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: but that will create 2 copies of same records...i only want to capture thos logs locally which were dropped, so that I can easily manually process them later

Comment: So, its kind of a high availability scenario. You can use horizontal scaling for your logs.Check this out - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/deploying-and-scaling.html

Comment: are you sure i cant extend socketappender or appenderskelton class to achieve what i want to in above case?

Comment: I was scrolling for implementing logging for my app. Take a look at this , https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html. Failover appender, So at first you have a Socket Appender, and if it fails, you can use a file Appender.

Answer (score 0):

Write to a local log file and use filebeat to ship the logs to logstash.  When logstash is unavailable, the logs will spool up locally (a "free" distributed cache).

There's a corner case if logstash is still down when your local log files are rotated...

Comment: are you sure i cant extend socketappender or appenderskelton class to achieve what i want to in above case?

Comment: I'm sure there are many other ways of solving the problem; I have you the elastic-y one.